# Are invertible measures strictly dense?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, haar-measure

Let $L_1(\mathbb T)$ be considered as a closed ideal of $M(\mathbb T)$, the Banach algebra of measures on the circle. Then $M(\mathbb T)$ can be identified with the multiplier algebra of $L_1(\mathbb T)$ and so it carries the strict topology.

*Is there a measure that cannot be approximated by invertible measures in the strict topology?*

Put differently, what is the strict closure of invertible measures in $M(\mathbb T)$?

EDIT: The answer is that invertible measures are strictly dense as:

1. $L_1$ is strictly dense in $M(\mathbb T)$.
2. Invertible elements of the unitization of $L_1$ are dense (in the norm).